# Efficient way to get float array from QByteArray with bigendian format

Tags: c++, c, qt

I have a QbyteArray variable with BigEndian Format
I want to get a float array from that variable with the minimum process.
what is the Fastest way to do?

Now I am using following code but its not efficient and I think there should be a better way?

please help

```
float getValue(QByteArray dataBytes, int i){    
    QByteArray data = dataBytes.mid(i*4, 4);
    qint32 level = qFromBigEndian<qint32>((uchar*)data.data());
    float result = level*1.0;
}

float *f = new float[20];
for (int i=0;i<20;i++){
     f[i] = getValue(myDataBytes, i);
}
```

Comment: question 1: are the encoded numbers integers? question 2: do you want it to be portable?

Comment: Just checking: The `QByteArray`  contains `qint32` and you want to convert each BigEndian integer to a regular float? Be aware that loses precision. You need a `double` to represent every possible `qint32`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not make an iterator and build a `std::vector`? No loss of efficiency plus complete safety:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

// simulate types
using qint32 = std::int32_t;

struct QByteArray {
  QByteArray mid(int, int);
  const std::uint8_t* data() const;
  const std::size_t* size() const;
};

// simulate functions
template<class T> T qFromBigEndian(const std::uint8_t*);

// iterator to convert big endian byte streams to ints
struct big_endian_ints_iterator 
  : std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, std::int32_t>
{

  big_endian_ints_iterator(const std::uint8_t * p) : ptr_(p) {}

  big_endian_ints_iterator& operator+=(std::size_t i) {
    ptr_ += 4 * i;
    return *this;
  }

  big_endian_ints_iterator& operator++() {
    ptr_ += 4;
    return *this;
  }

  big_endian_ints_iterator operator++(int) {
    auto tmp = *this;
    ptr_ += 4;
    return tmp;
  }

  value_type operator*() const {
    return qFromBigEndian<std::int32_t>(ptr_);
  }

  bool operator!=(const big_endian_ints_iterator& r) const {
    return r.ptr_ != ptr_;
  }

  bool operator==(const big_endian_ints_iterator& r) const {
    return r.ptr_ == ptr_;
  }

  const std::uint8_t* ptr_;
};

big_endian_ints_iterator operator+(big_endian_ints_iterator l, std::size_t r)
{
  return l += r;
}

std::vector<float> test(QByteArray const& myDataBytes)
{
  auto first = big_endian_ints_iterator(myDataBytes.data());
  std::vector<float> f(first, first + 20);
  return f;
}
```

proof on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/g/PG3H2V

Comment: How is this "complete safety"? Your code is only doing pointer arithmetic and is not safer than the code in the question. Try `
  std::vector<float> f(first, first + 21);` and you'll have `_ptr` pointing after the QByteArray buffer, possibly in unallocated memory.

Comment: @BenjaminT I mean safety in terms of the management of the vector of floats. I am not familiar with QByteArray, but I am sure there must be a way to check its length before initialising the vector.

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer, remove the call to `QByteArray::mid()` and use only `const` functions to prevent extra copy-on-write. Other than that I don't think you can be more efficient, maybe inline the function.

```
inline float getValue(const QByteArray &dataBytes, int i){  
    const qint32 level = qFromBigEndian<qint32>(&static_cast<const qint32 *>(dataBytes.constData())[i]);
    return level*1.0;
}
```